# Pass object from SQL query function to a separate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, promise, nested-function

I'm new to node and promises. I have two files - `server.js` and `db.js`

`server.js` imports `db.js` as modules.

I'm fetching some data from a SQL database in a `db.js` module and I'm trying to pass that data to a function in `server.js`.
I've successfully fetched the data from database, but when I try to pass it to the function in `server.js`, it only returns an `undefined` value.

**Here's the code**

**server.js**

```
const db = require('./db.js');

app.post('/api/trigger-push-msg/', function (req, res) {
  return getSubscriptionsFromDatabase()
  .then(function(subscriptions) {

    // Do something

  });
});

function getSubscriptionsFromDatabase() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let subscriptions = db.getSubscriptions();

    console.log(subscriptions);  // this only prints "undefined"

    if (subscriptions != undefined) {
      resolve(subscriptions);
    } else {
      reject("No");  // this executes
    }
  })
}
```

**db.js**

```
module.exports = {
  getSubscriptions: function() {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM subscriptions";

    con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);  // this prints the same result as I want
      return result;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You should put the `return new Promise(…)` in the `getSubscriptions` function. You cannot `return` from that callback, you can only call `resolve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSubscriptions` doesn't have a return statement

and considering that there's some async content in it you should wrap all inside a promise and trigger the subsequent logic only after it resolves.

```
module.exports = {
  getSubscriptions: function() {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM subscriptions";
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve(result);
      })
    })
  }
}
```

then:

```
function getSubscriptionsFromDatabase() {
  return db.getSubscriptions()
  .then(function(subscriptions){
     return subscriptions;
   })
}
```

and in your route:

```
app.post('/api/trigger-push-msg/', function (req, res) {
 getSubscriptionsFromDatabase()
  .then(function(subscriptions) {
    res.send(subscriptions);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    res.sendStatus(500);
  })
});
```

Comment: I added a console log statement before `resolve(subscriptions);` but it doesn't get executed at all.

Comment: i've fixed the code, check if it works now :)